# How to detect A-GPS in device?

Tags: android, android-location

I am working on an application in which latitude and longitude of the device is required. I have used GPS Provider to get latitude and longitude and it works fine, but when I checked my app on HTC Desire 816 which has Android v4.4.2 (KitKat), its not working. It always shows GPS is disable.

This device has Assisted GPS (A-GPS) and GLONASS, this is available in many latest devices. My question is how can I detect A-GPS through my code as code for standalone GPS is not working for A-GPS.

**Method for getting latitude & longitude:**

```
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (location == null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
```

Comment: What do you get on the HTC Desire 816 when you iterate through the results of LocationManager.getAllProviders()?  Also have you considered using the LocationManager.getBestProvider() method to avoid bothering with  where exactly your location data was coming from?

Comment: @Ashish Did you get a solution to this ?